# Find the smallest value of the product $ab$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

From the 2018  Moroccan Mathematics Olympiad:

> Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z^2}$ such that $a+b$ is a solution of the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$. Find the smallest value of the product $ab$. ($\mathbb Z$ contains 0)

---

**My Approach:**

I've solved it by an extremely bashy method, which I don't think is worth showing. I just used the properties of quadratic equations, and basic divisibility properties. I then got all the possible solutions, and simply calculated the possible products. I found the m

**Question :**

> Can one find the desired minimum without finding all solutions to the given equation?

Edit: Basically what I did, is find the equivalent equation: $(2a+b)^2=-b(b+2a+2)$, Now notice: $gcd(2a+b;b+2a+2)=1$ or $=2$, try all cases and get all solutions.

Edit 2: The solution given in the first edit, isn't the long bashy solution.

Comment: Which is the answer you got?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say you wish to find the smallest value of $ab$, you don't mean absolute magnitude? That is, $-11$ is considered smaller than $-3$? And the relevant equation is $x=a+b \Rightarrow 2a^2+3ab+b^2+b=0$? That means one of $a,b$ is a negative integer.

Comment: @KeithBackman Yes, $-11$ is considered smaller than $-3$. And yes, the equation is: $2a^2+3ab+b^2+b=0$

Comment: @jjagmath I found -1

Comment: I confirm the equation and for sure a=-6 and b=9 is a solution of that equation thus the minimum can't be 0

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D. Indeed, I somehow messed up the calculations

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only integer solutions are (-6,9), (-6,8), (0,0) (0,-1) but I need to write down a proof.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $(b-4)^2=4^2+(4a+3b)^2$. But the only pythagorean triple with a side length of $4$ is $(3,4,5)$, together with the degenerate $(0,4,4)$. Hence $b-4=\pm4$ or $\pm5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from $2a^2+3ab+b^2+b=0$, use the quadratic formula to obtain an expression for $a$:
$$a=\frac{-3b\pm \sqrt{9b^2-8(b^2+b)}}{4}$$
This only has integer solutions when $(b^2-8b)$ is a perfect square. This occurs when $b \in \{-1,0,8,9\}$

Next, an expression for $ab$ can be stated without finding any particular solutions to the original equation
$$ab=\frac{-3b\pm \sqrt{9b^2-8(b^2+b)}}{4}\cdot b$$
Substituting the acceptable values of $b$ into that formula yields $-54$ as its smallest value, without ever identifying any of the values of $a$ or solutions to the original equation.